# setAutoCreateRowSorter not working for Int's

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I am trying to sort integers in my 2nd column of my JTable. I used `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);` but it is sorting by strings. I am trying to write some code to get around this but I cannot get it to work.

```
DefaultTableModel m = new DefaultTableModel();
String columnName = "Occurrences";  
m.addColumn("String");
m.addColumn(columnName);
JTable table = new JTable(m);
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);


if (m.findColumn(columnName) == 2)
    {
            return Integer.class;
    } else {

            return null;
    }
```

This is the only way I can get this to even compile by adding `Class<Integer>` into my function. This doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't very clear, but if you want the second column class to be Integer, you just need to override it:

```
DefaultTableModel m = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        if (column == 1) {
            return Integer.class;
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(column);
    }
};
```

Comment: I am getting this error for `return super.getColumnClass(column);` The method getColumnClass(int) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: Then you're not using the code I gave you in my answer. This method must be in the anonymous subclass of DefaultTableModel.

Comment: is there a way to just define a column as an integer column?

Comment: Yes. That's what my answer does. It defines the second column as an column containing instances of Integer.

Comment: okay. I meant more along the lines of `model.addColumn();` as an int

Comment: @user2007843 What _nope_? Do you expect to do any useful programming without reading any api doc? That's asking for failure ;-)